# Create a partial class with inheritance in aspx without recompiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am really new to C#/VB as a web coding language so apologies early if this is rudimentary

I have a vendor .NET solution i need to add an .aspx page to, which I've managed to do, but there are missing HTML items that are placed by backend .vb file code (we have the uncompiled code as well as the site code)

so for example, Report.aspx
uncompiled

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="jobber.VU.Report"
 CodeFile="Report.aspx.vb" %>

 <%@ Register TagPrefix="VU" Namespace="jobber.VU.Controls"  %>
```

compiled

```
 <%@ page language="vb" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="jobber.VU.Report, 
  App_Web_report.aspx.cdcab7d2" enableEventValidation="false" %>

 <%@ Register TagPrefix="VU" Namespace="jobber.VU.Controls"  %>
```

the VB backend

```
Namespace jobber.VU
    Partial Class Report
        Inherits ActionBase

    End Class
End Namespace
```

How do I replicate that in just an ASPX page?

I tried this

```
 <%@ page language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Debug="true" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="VU" Namespace="jobber.VU.Controls"  %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="jobber.VU.ActionBase"  %>
 <VU:metatags id="headers1" format="none" runat="server"></VU:metatags>
```

and VU.Controls comes back fine, but the ActionBase class is not executing

I also attempted a `<script runat=server`, but it never took off the ground

Comment: Why do you need a partial class if you have access to the source already?

Comment: I guess the question should be stated "how can i do this without recompiling and just in the aspx"

Comment: Are you trying to create a 2nd page or just modify an existing one?

Comment: If the backend class `jobber.VU.Report` expects certain HTML elements to be on the page, you'll need to make sure your 2nd page has those in place as well. For example, if the page class is trying to insert controls into a control on the page (ex: a Panel), if the panel isn't there and the codebehind doesn't handle the failure gracefully, it will throw an exception.

I'm still not quite sure exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Also, you can have multiple pages inherit from the same page. So if you want to duplicate the functionality of the `jobber.VU.Report` page, just add a new page and inherit from it.

Comment: the Inherited ActionBase builds some html based on the query string then inserts it to the aspx page...I can't figure out how to have the ActionBase class do its job, because importing it did not work

Comment: rattrick, indeed having the second page inherit the other's class did work, i know i had tried that already, but i was missing an html element for it to insert/append to...if you make an answer i will upvote/accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple pages inherit from the same page. So if you want to duplicate the functionality of the 'jobber.VU.Report page', just add a new page and inherit from it.